# Request exceeds the maximum allowed database in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-xe

I'm using 18c oracle, while writing data to a spreadsheet I got the error

`ORA-12954: The request exceeds the maximum allowed database size of 12 GB.`

After that I deleted some data from tables (200 mb). But it did not help, this error continues to appear.But when i deleted the entries from this table (which i was trying to break the record into) it earned. How do I fix this problem ??. Entries in table 48000, its size is 34 MB

Comment: Do you drop a lot of tables? Perhaps dropping and re-creating "temp tables" on the fly? Maybe your tablespace is full of dead tables. If so trying `purge recyclebin`.

Comment: You'll get this when Oracle tries to extend the table. To allow inserting into that table, you have to either (a) delete some other data from the *same* table, or (b) reduce the tablespace occupied by other objects (tables or indexes). For more ideas: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/reclaiming-unused-space

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're using **Express Edition**, aren't you? Although free to use (even for production purposes), it limits user data to 12 GB and there's no way you can override that limit. If you do need more space, you'll have to upgrade to e.g. Standard Edition, but that costs dear money.

What you could try to do is to

- export database you have
- remove it entirely from your computer
- install a brand new database
- import previously exported data into it

Hopefully, it'll help. Please, before dropping anything, confirm that such an approach actually *will* help. If not, you'd do it in vain.

Comment: but i don't understand why when i deleted the data from the second spreadsheet it didn't help, and when from the one i write to, everything is fine! The same tables are in the same scheme

Comment: I don't know how Oracle calculates space occupied. Perhaps is it size of data files (which are now extended to 12GB).